# Android-heap: Image in AlertDialog taking up huge heap memory and not freeing it up

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-dialog, android-memory

I have a particular fragment containing an image. On click of the image I scale up the image and show it in a dialog with some title.

All this works fine.

While using DDMS I saw the heap memory shoots up by ~4Mb on open of the dialog box and on close of it that is not freed up.

And hence doing this a couple of times takes up huge heap memory.

```
public class ImageOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    String article_title ;
    String article_url;

    public ImageOnClickListener(String imageUrl, String title) {
        article_title = title;
        article_url = imageUrl;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View layout = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment, null);

        TextView articleTitle = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.image_title);
        articleTitle.setText(article_title);
        articleTitle.setTextSize(MainActivity.fontSize +10);
        articleTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.white));

        URL imageUri = null;
        try {
            imageUri = new URL(article_url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
        try {
            bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUri.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
        int height = display.getHeight();  

        int w = (int) (width*0.8);
        int h = (int) (height*0.8);

        ImageView imageObject = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.image_main);
        int imgWidth = bitmapImage.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = bitmapImage.getHeight();
        int ratio = w/imgWidth;

        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, imgWidth*ratio,imgHeight*ratio, true);
        imageObject.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w,h);
        imageObject.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

        alertDialog = imageDialog.setView(layout).create();
        int dialogWidth = (int) (width*0.9);
        int dialogHeight = (int) (height*0.9);
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth,dialogHeight);


    }
}
```

Basically I was looking for a way to free up that memory on dismiss of the dialog.

Comment: How do you measure the memory? Does it still not free up the memory after you force a GC in your IDE (i.e. Eclipse)? Java/Dalvik is a VM and memory is managed by the virtual machine. Objects that are not referenced anymore remain into the memory until the next garbage collection which is to be determined by the VM when the next GC happens. Using `System.gc()` will force the garbage collection from code.

Comment: It does not free up even after calling Garbage collector.